# Creating a class that encapsulates coupled React components, then setting that class as React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, react-redux

I have a React Component that renders a `FullDayRouteMap` component taking in state accumulators coupled with several `SingleRouteMap` components that each conduct a callback which update the state accumulators.

The FullDayRouteMap components then takes these updated accumulators as props and re-renders.

I wanted to encapsulate the coupled functionality of the two components (i.e. the accumulators and the callback) in a class so I can reuse this feature in several parts of my app and so I made a Manager class that is set as the state of the parent React component in its constructor.

Everything is working but I am wondering if this is good practice. Something I am kind of iffy about is the fact that I have to pass in the parent component to this manager class in order to force it to re-render upon an accumulator update within the

Here is the code for this manager class (shortened for conciseness):

```
import React from 'react';
import SingleRouteMap from './SingleRouteMap';
import FullDayRouteMap from './FullDayRouteMap';

class Manager {

    constructor(component) {
        this.distanceMetresAcc = 0;
        this.travelTimeSecondsAcc = 0;
    }


    initSingleRouteMap(bookingNodes) {
        bookingNodes.push(
            <SingleRouteMap
                onDirectionsDataLoaded={this.onSingleRouteLoaded} />);
    }

    getFullDayRouteMap() {
        return <FullDayRouteMap
            totalDistanceTravelledMetres={this.distanceMetresAcc}
            totalSecondsTravelled={this.travelTimeSecondsAcc}
        />
    }

    onSingleRouteLoaded = (durationSeconds, distanceMetres) => {
        this.travelTimeSecondsAcc += durationSeconds;
        this.distanceMetresAcc += distanceMetres;
        this.component.forceUpdate();
    };
}
```

And in my parent component, this is what I do:

```
Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            manager: new Manager(this)
        }
    }
}
```

The render function then just calls `this.state.manager.initSingleRouteMap` and `this.state.manager.getFullDayRouteMap` to dynamically place these components in the UI.

Comment: You should use a React Hoc and define your state in it. this way, all your components wrapped in your Hoc would have the same functionalities and state structure 
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: You're breaking a ton of React conventions, to the point where a single answer really can't cover everything.  A quick rundown;  You shouldn't need to use `forceUpdate`.  You shouldn't need to create any classes to manage components for you (that's what react *does*).  State should be an abstraction of the current disposition of your component, it should not be an API.

Comment: @gravityplanx if I were to remove the class and instantiate these components in the react component itself, the accumulators would be held in state and the callback function would also be a part of the parent component. I would then have to add all of these moving parts to every parent component where I want this feature implemented, which is a lot of copy-pasting of code. How would I implemented coupled components like this in a modular manner?

Comment: As @soupette mentioned, that is what an HOC is for.  I'll throw a rough example in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving with an HOC

```
function withRouteAcc(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                distanceMetresAcc: 0,
                travelTimeSecondsAcc: 0,
                bookingNodeCount: 0
            };
        }

        initSingleRouteMap() {
            this.setState(
                (state) => (
                    { bookingNodeCount: state.bookingNodeCount + 1 }
                )
            );
        }

        onSingleRouteLoaded(durationSeconds, distanceMetres) {
            this.setState((state) => (
                    {
                        distanceMetresAcc: state.distanceMetresAcc + distanceMetres,
                        travelTimeSecondsAcc: state.travelTimeSecondsAcc +
                                              durationSeconds
                    }
                )
            );
        }

        getBookingNodes() {
            return this.state.bookingNodeCount.map(() => {
                return <SingleRouteMap onDirectionsDataLoaded={this.onSingleRouteLoaded}/>;
            });
        }

        getFullDayRouteMap() {
            return <FullDayRouteMap totalDistanceTravelledMetres={this.distanceMetresAcc}
                                    totalSecondsTravelled={this.travelTimeSecondsAcc}/>;
        }

        render() {
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} 
                              bookingNodes={this.getBookingNodes()}
                              fullDayRouteMap={this.getFullDayRouteMap()}
                              initSingleRouteMap={this.initSingleRouteMap}/>;
        }
    };
}

//Usage: withRouteAcc(ParentComponent);
// Now `ParentComponent` can access `bookingNodes` and `fullDayRouteMap` from props, as well as a callback for `initSingleRouteMap`
```